# How to format list output in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to format output of an index and list from this:

```
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
The answers should be: 
['b', 'c', 'a', 'c']`
```

To more like this:

```
[6]  b   
[7]  c
[8]  a    
[9]  c
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
print( "Here are the questions the you got wrong: ")
for i in range (0, 10):
    if q[i] != answers[i]:
        print ( [i+1],)
    else:
        ("You got all of the questions correct, Good Job. ")
print("The answers should be: ")
print(wrongList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print `answers[i]`:

```
for i in range (10):
    print("[{}] {}".format(i+1, answers[i])
```

If there are only ten answers you can use `enumerate` with a starting value of 1, `enumerate(answers, start=1)` or if there are more the than ten you will have to slice it:

```
 for i  answer in enumerate(answers[:10], start=1)
```

You can also [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and forget indexing:

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(answers, p),1):
    if a != b:
       print("[{}] {}".format(count, a))
    else:
       print("You got all of the questions correct, Good Job. ")
```

`"[{}] {}".format(count, a)` is using  [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) which is generally the preferred method.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't collect the `wrongList` but it'll be easy to do with:

```
print("The answers should be: ")
for i in range (0, 10):
    if q[i] != answers[i]:
        print (q[i], answers[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to loop through a list and get the index:

```
for i, answer in enumerate(answers):
    print("[%s] %s" % (i, answer))
```

If the `print` statement doesn't make sense, take a look at the documentation for [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Comment: The enumeration starts at 6, no?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi The question doesn't make it clear. It sounds like there are 10 questions.